# Issue on Setting Bootstrap Active Button Background Color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/qtqahFJLKt) and let me know why I am not set the background color for active state of button in bootstrap 3? what I am expecting is setting the background color to red after the click which works until the mouse is over the button but as soon as the mouse leaves it changes to transparent again!

Thanks

```
.btn-sample
 {
  text-shadow: none;
  color: white;
  background:transparent;
  border:2px solid red;
  color:red;
}
.btn-sample:hover
 {
  text-shadow: none;
  color: white;
  background:red;
}
.btn-sample:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-sample.active {
   background-color: red;
}
.btn-sample:active:focus {
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: red; 
}
.btn-sample.active:focus{
     background-color: red;
   }
.btn-sample:active:focus{
      background-color: red;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap does not automatically attach the `active` class when you click a button. You need a bit of jQuery (or you could use javascript) to do it for you.

Try this:

```
$('.btn-sample').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[Updated your link here](http://www.bootply.com/sA3WvaWPmn)